# Distance from $(1,0,0,...)$ to closed subspace in $l^2$

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, limits, vector-spaces, metric-spaces

can someone help me with this problem?

Find distance $d(x,L_n)$ in $l^2$ from $x=(1,0,0,...)$ to closed subspace $L_n=\{x \in l^2: x=(x_1,x_2,...), \sum_{k=1}^n x_k = 0\}$. Also, find $\lim_{n \to \infty} d(x,L_n)$.

I tried the following:
I took $y \in L_n$ and calculated
$$d(x,y) = \sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} |x_k-y_k|^2} \leq \sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} |x_k|^2} + \sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} |y_k|^2} = 1+||y||,$$
but I'm stuck here.

I also did this
$$0 \leq \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} y_k^2 \leq (\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} y_k)^2 = (\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty} y_k)^2 \to 0, n \to \infty \implies ||y||\to 0, n \to \infty,$$
but this doesn't help me to solve my problem.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What comes just before this?  Is there something about "orthogonal projection"?

Comment: No, nothing about that :(

Answer (score 1):

First, show that $L_n^{\perp}=\text{span}\big\{e_1+\dots + e_n\big\}$.

The distance between $e_1$ and $L_n$ is the magnitude of the orthogonal projection of $e_1$ onto $L_n^{\perp}$ i.e. $$d\left(e_1,L_n\right)=\Big\|\text{Proj}_{L_n^{\perp}}(e_1)\Big\|=\frac{|e_1\cdot (e_1 + \dots +e_n)|}{\|e_1+\dots +e_n\|}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$$

Comment: Thank you, but I don't understand much of this. Any hints on how should I show the first part?